# Connecting to an MQTT Broker over Websocket using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I have been using the native JS `websocket` object to build apps that use WS to communicate with the server. I have set up a Mosquitto MQTT broker and have enabled ws connections on the server.

I'm not a big fan of importing third-party libraries if it can be avoided but can't seem to find any examples of how to connect just using the native JS `websocket` object.

Does this mean it's not possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible, but you will just end up totally re-implementing the whole MQTT protocol ([spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html)). MQTT over Websockets is just the raw TCP protocol tunnelled over a websocket connection.

Just use the [Paho Javascript](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) client and save yourself a lot of effort and testing.